# Bootstrap 4 table align issue

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a problem about aligning some items.

In the following [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/4053/) I have 2 options `Option1` and `Option2`. I would like to align the toggle switches with the ones in the first two rows.

Basically I want the toggle switches to be in the second column of the table and the text that are below them in the first column.

Any ideas how can I solve it ?

Thank you

Comment: You need to add some extra rows and split the content accordingly - http://jsfiddle.net/3p9mp2rv/3/

Comment: thanks but that's not what I'm asking. `Option1` and `Option2` are part of the 3rd row, they aren't in different rows

Answer (score 1):

You're using bootstrap, so I would ditch the tables. But if you must use the tables, simply make the table rows and columns uniform.

Here's an updated fiddle with the [correct nesting](http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/4063/)

```
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead style="" class="">
          <tr class="d-flex">
              <th class="col-6">My </th>
              <th class="col-6"></th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr class="d-flex">
              <td class="text-sm-left col-sm-11">some text
              </td>
              <td class="text-sm-right col-sm-1">
                <div class="switch">
                  <input id="cmn-toggle-5" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round-flat" type="checkbox">
                  <label for="cmn-toggle-5"></label>
                </div>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="d-flex">
              <td class="text-sm-left col-sm-11">some text
              </td>
              <td class="text-sm-right col-sm-1">
                <div class="switch">
                  <input id="cmn-toggle-5" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round-flat" type="checkbox">
                  <label for="cmn-toggle-5"></label>
                </div>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="d-flex">
              <td class="col-sm-12">testtexttex :</td>
          </tr>

          <tr class="d-flex">
              <td class="col-sm-11">Option1
                 <button type="button" class='btn btn-secondary '>
                     <span class="fa fa-envelope"></span>
                 </button></td>
              <td class="col-sm-1">
                <div class="switch">
                  <input id="cmn-toggle-5" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round-flat" type="checkbox">
                  <label for="cmn-toggle-5"></label>
                </div>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="d-flex">
              <td class="col-sm-11">Option2
                 <button type="button" class='btn btn-secondary '>
                     <span class="fa fa-envelope"></span>
                 </button></td>
              <td class="col-sm-1">
                <div class="switch">
                  <input id="cmn-toggle-5" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round-flat" type="checkbox">
                  <label for="cmn-toggle-5"></label>
                </div>
              </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```